# Measurability in Tonelli's theorem proof of $E(X^\alpha) = \int_0^\infty \alpha t^{\alpha-1} P(X \geq t) dt$

Tags: probability-theory

To show this result, I consider the product space $(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^+, \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^+)}, P \otimes \lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure. Then I define

$$A :=\{(\omega,t): X(\omega) \geq t \}$$

Which is a $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^+)}$ measurable. I then want to use Tonelli's theorem on the integral

$$\int_{\Omega \times  \mathbb{R}^+} \alpha t^{\alpha-1} \mathbf{1}_A d(P \otimes \lambda)$$

I can see how the proof follows from the use of Tonelli's theorem, however I'm not sure how to argue that $$\alpha t^{\alpha-1} \mathbf{1}_A$$ is $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R}^+)}$ measurable to satisfy the conditions of Tonelli's theorem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Start wit $X$ as a simple function, then build things up to nonnegative functions by monotone convergence arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I let $X$ be a simple function such as $$X = \sum c_i \mathbb{1}_{F_i}$$ for $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$ I'm not sure how to show - with this simple function - that $$\alpha t^{\alpha-1} \mathbb{1}_A$$ is measurable. Are there any further hints you could give?